# pl sql trigger insert values from a sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

```
create table userdetail(
  userdetailsid number(3) not null,
  userid varchar2(5),
  firstname varchar2(15),
  lastname varchar2(15),
  email varchar2(15),
  primary key (userdetailsid)
);

create sequence Iseq
start with 1
increment by 1;

create or replace trigger userDetailInsert
before insert on userdetail
begin
  :userdetailsid:=Iseq.nextval;
end;
```

the error I get is as follows:

```
Error at line 2: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'USERDETAILSID'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `:` from `:userdetailsid` or use `:old.`/`:new` in combination with `for each row`:

```
create or replace trigger userDetailInsert
before insert on userdetail for each row
begin
   :new.userdetailsid:=Iseq.nextval;
end;
```

If you use a `:` the column name is considered to be a [bind variable](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/literals-substitution-variables-and-bind-variables.php).

Generally said, if you want to reference old or new values use `:old.userdetailsid` resp.  `:new.userdetailsid`.

Comment: thanks but i'm still getting another error when i remove the ':', Error at line 2: PL/SQL: Statement ignored


1. create or replace trigger userDetailInsert
2. before insert on userdetail
3. begin
4.    userdetailsid:=Iseq.nextval;

Comment: Ok, wasn't sure what you tried to achieve, but I think you want to overwrite all `id`'s with sequence values? In that case you need to add `for each row` and `:new.`. See changes above :)