# How to use oracle sequence in Python dataframe - Python (Pandas)

Tags: python, oracle, dataframe, sequence

I have a sequence in oracle that I want to use to insert my data from a data frame in Python into an oracle database. I have already a sequence in oracle that I want to use.

I have a python data frame below that I want to consider a specific column as "ID" in order to put sequence:

| ID | Name | NN |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sara | 1234 |
| 2 | Mina | 6547 |

I have already a sequence in oracle which I call "SQ_test"

PS: I found how to create the sequence but I do not know how to use that or use that in my panda's data frame.
here is the function that I can use:

```
def get_change_id():

   id = cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)

   sql_query_sq = """
       BEGIN 
          :next_id := SQ_TEST.nextval; 
       END; 
   """

   cursor.execute(sql_query, {"next_id":id})

   change_id = id.getvalue()

   return change_id
```

Comment: You can simply reference it in the INSERT statement you build, ie, insert into XXX ( id, name, nn) values ( sq_text.nextval, :val1, :val2);

Comment: my seq is in the oracle but my table is in the pandas dataframe

Comment: Consider doing the sequence logic in the DB with a [trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19758238/4799035). Or use the newer syntax CREATE TABLE mytable (name VARCHAR2(10), nn NUMBER, id NUMBER(11) GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY(START WITH 1)). With these solutions your Pandas code just needs to handle inserting the NAME and NN values because the ID column will automatically get updated from the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to create a sequence by creating a table, after that whenever I want to insert my, automatically sequences are created and inserted in their column.
How:
When I create my table when I consider the type of my column, I also write down the sequence creation, Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME
(
 ID NUMBER(38,0) generated by default as identity primary key,
 ...
);
```

We need to be careful that till we insert the data into a table, the sequence will be continued, but if we want to restart the sequence, we need to drop the table.